# Issues with findOneAndUpdate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am posting to the /update route.

This works because I can see my console.log() items printing in the terminal, see here:

[image]

However, my code seems to be totally ignoring the find one and update function.

All I want to do is run a put request to the route and have it update the post.

Here is my AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/admin-panel/update/",
    method: "PUT",
    data: $data,
    success: function(data, status) {
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        window.location.href = "/admin-panel/update/";
    },
    error: function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
    }
});
```

And here is the put request handler in the backend:

```
router.put("/:action", function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.params.action.toLowerCase() == "update") {

        console.log("started")

        var timelineItems = require("../schemas/timelineItems.js");

         console.log("timeline items model inserted:", timelineItems)

        timelineItems.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.id}, function (err, post) {
            if (err) {
                next(err);
            }

            console.log("post:", post)

            res.send("item updated!");
        });

        console.log("should be done");

    } else {
        var err = new Error('Access forbidden, please login!');
        err.status = 403;
        next(err);
    }
});
```

I know that the right data is being run in the put request also as I checked the value of $data on the view and req.body on the backend too, so I am unsure why this isnt working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your findOneAndUpdate query missing update parameter.

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate([conditions], [update], [options], [callback])
```

Check this [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)